# using dict vs class __dict__ method to format strings

Tags: python

I have been using dict to format strings

```
s = '%(name1)s %(name2)s'
d = {}
d['name1'] = 'asdf'
d['name2'] = 'whatever'
result = s % d
```

I just realized that I can do this with a class and using the **dict** method
instead:

```
s = '%(name1)s %(name2)s'
class D : pass
d = D()
d.name1 = 'asdf'
d.name2 = 'whatever'
result = s % d.__dict__
```

(obviously I do this for bigger strings, and many keys).

Is there any disadvantage to the class approach that I am overlooking?
Or is there a better method of doing this string formatting that I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use new-style formatting, which allows getattr and getitem operators in format string:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> x.x = 1
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> "{0[a]} {0[b]} {1.x}".format(d, x)
'1 2 1'
```

Regarding disadvantages of your approach - object's `__dict__` is limited to whatever attributes and methods particular instance has, so any attribute/method defined at class level will fail:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     x1 = 1
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> x.x2 = 2
>>> x.__dict__
{'x2': 2}
>>> x.x1
1
>>> x.__dict__['x1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'x1'
```

It also does not work with `__slots__` and `__getattribute__` overrides.

Comment: What you mean to say is that `__dict__` will not contain *class-level* attributes.  Attributes defined in a superclass `__init__` will show up in a subclass instance's `__dict__` (assuming you remembered to have the subclass `__init__` call the superclass `__init__`).

Comment: @Paul, I've illustrated it in my answer. Class `X2` has attribute `x2`. But instance of this class, `x`, does not have `x2` in it's `__dict__`. When you do `x.x2`, python does MRO look-up for it, and takes value from `X2.__dict__`. `x.__dict__` will hold ONLY values explicitly bound to this particular instance.

Comment: @Daniel, so when you said "inheritance" did you mean "the instance inheriting from its class"? That's a funny use of the term, I usually think of inheritance as being one class from another.  Attributes defined as `self.name = something` get defined on the instance, and will be stored in the instance's `__dict__`, regardless whether this happend in the derived class or superclass. Your point with respect to the OP is that the OP's plan to pass `d.__dict__` as the mapping for string interpolation fails for any class attribute; I just think calling this an *inheritance* issue is not correct.

Comment: @Paul, no, when I said 'inheritance' i meant class X2 inheriting from class X1 in my example. Instance vs class was mentioned in next sentence, "Moreover, it will not contain class-level attributes too". In general, I was just pointing out that `getattr(instance, attr)` is definitely not same as `instance.__dict__[attr]` and therefore it could cause unexpected key errors.

Comment: @Daniel - this statement "your instance's `__dict__` will NOT contain inherited attributes" is not completely correct. It won't contain inherited class attributes, but then, it won't contain *any* class attributes. On the other hand, it *will* contain inherited instance attributes. Write `__init__` methods for X1 and X2, be sure `X2.__init__` calls `X1.__init__`, and assign instance attributes in both. An instance of X2 will contain both instance attributes.

Comment: @Paul, indeed, mentioning inheritance here is excessive, fixed and added other cases where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider creating dict using keyword arguments, e.g.:

```
d = dict(name1='foo', name2='bar')
```

Or using format's keyword arguments:

```
"{name1} baz {name2}".format(name1='foo', name2='bar')
```